# custom node type that save to a custom table

Tags: nodes

I’m trying to convert one of my sites into a Drupal site. The site is a travel site and has a lot of data on there, so I’m trying to convert my database tables to custom node types, but my tables are large,  I have about 30 different tables with a total of about 200+ fields.

If I would just convert all the fields to CCK fields I would end up with a database with 400 to 500 tables, I don’t like that, so I’m trying to create custom node types that save to custom tables.

Does anybody know how to do this, and if you know of an example somewhere that would be great

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best off if you use the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import your data into Drupal. Messing with the database configuration yourself just because you "don't like that" a lot of tables would be generated seems like a lot of work for not much potential benefit.

If you're worried about filling up the Drupal database, it is possible to use one database for Drupal's content and configuration, and another for data that you're using Drupal to expose to users. D7 boasts [master/slave database configuration support](http://drupal.org/node/310071). It is also possible to integrate with databases that Drupal does not support for its main configuration database, e.g. [Mongo](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore the Entity API module. You will have a lot of custom coding ahead of you. But when you're done, your new entities can act just like nodes.